# Azure Dev Ops Repository via NPM

Tags: npm, azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out a way to have one repository that is my front-end code pulled into another repository that houses my application code. Both of these repos are hosted by Azure Dev Ops, however they are under different accounts (if that matters).

I have followed the directions I found on [Microsoft's site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) for setting up the `.npmrc` file on my development machine, but I'm getting lost at how to structure my URL on the application site to pull in my front-end code package.

Everything I've tried has given me a authentication error so I must be missing something.

Comment: Dose my answer help you to solve your issue/confuse, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks

Answer (score 0):

According your statements, I noticed that you need to pull the front-end code into your application code repository. Since these two repos are under different accounts and hosted by Azure Dev Ops.

We recommend you can try to Import the front-end code repository to your application code project. And then we can refer the doc: [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops).
Here are the detail steps:

1. Go to your front-end code repos and use the admin account to create a new PAT with full access.
2. Go to the application code project, then use the ‘[Import repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#import-into-a-new-repo)’
3. Create a new pipeline and check out the both repos.

[image]

And for the authentication error, you can try to use the [npm Authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#with-a-task-runner-eg-make-gulp-work) in your pipeline.